# Equal opeartor not working with Array in Solidty

Tags: arrays, function, blockchain, solidity, revert

I wrote a simple solidity programme:-

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16 ;
 contract arr
 {     uint256[] public n ;
       uint256 x = 0 ;

  function pl(uint256 a ) public
    {
      n[x] = a ;
      x++ ;
     }
 }
```

It is showing below error

[Error showing image while calling function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTgQz.png)

It reads that

> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The
> called function should be payable if you send value and the value you
> send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction
> to get more information.

I am new to solidity. Can anyone please explain it to me that why = opearator is not working with arrays. I read that Solidity is similar to Javascript & in Jsp it is working fine ?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign into a non-existent index.

Use `.push()` to add new item to the array.

```
function pl(uint256 a) public {
    n.push(a);
}
```

Comment: @BrijeshRoy It can have up to `2^256` items but the initial length of the array is 0, and you need to use `push()` to add a new value each time... What you're describing in your comment sounds like a `mapping` with a key of type `uint256` - code example `mapping (uint256 => bool) values;`

Comment: Solidity is on the lines of Javascript & in Javascript it is working fine in this manner as I did in my question.                                                                                                                      ```var arr4 = new Array();
arr4[0] = 45;
console.log(arr4);                                                                                                                            ```

Answer (score 0):

In the Dynamic array in Solidity you can't do what you are trying to do.
Here is the fixed array code :

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16 ;
 contract arr
 {     uint256[4] public n ;
       uint256 x = 0 ;

  function pl(uint256 a ) public
    {
      n[x] = a ;
      x++ ;
     }
 }
```

This code works for me as I am declaring the size of the array.
If you really wanna do it dynamically you have to first push a value in the dynamic array, then you can change a value with "Equal" sign. Here is the dynamic array code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16 ;
 contract arr
 {     uint256[] public n ;
       uint256 x = 0 ;

  function pl(uint256 a ) public
    {
      n.push();
      n[x] = a ;
      x++ ;
     }
 }
```